# How to stop Android Studio AVD Emulator from crashing

Tags: android, kvm, hsm

I installed Android Studio on Ubuntu 20.04

I want to use the emulator (i had tried other tools like and but they were too confusing)

Initially I was getting messages about `/dev/kvm` not being found.

I went into hardware setting and enabled HSM.
This seemed to help as devices now come up.

However shortly after they appear, they show the google page but then my machine freezes and keyboard and mouse are frozen and I have to reboot every time.  The pixel2 for example bring up the phone, looks just like the real thing, google page shows with spinner then crashes.

I am trying a pixel2 and a foldable, same issue for both.

Answer (score 2):

One answer was to choose software over hardware for the emulation ('Graphics') dropdown.

However - this only worked for a very limited set of devices, for example a Nexus 6 or a 10.1 WXGA tablet.  these devices show the option to use software for graphics acceleration instead oif requiring hardweare.

Other models such as pixel2, pixel3, foldables, etc. don't have that option and when they are used they crash my machine.

[image]

For Nexus 6, which works, here is the emulator:

[image]